# react-google-maps Multiple markers and Info Window

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I need to do create a Info Window for each Marker I have in my map. I can see the markers on the map, but when I click over the marker to get the InfoWindow, I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOpen' of undefined`, referencing to `this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})` in the `onToggleOpen`.

Thanks on behalf

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ markers: [], isOpen: false })
  }

componentDidMount() {
    let list = { restaurants : []}
    database.ref('..').on('value', .. => {
            ...
            })
            this.setState({ markers:  list.restaurants});
        })

}

onToggleOpen(){
    this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
}


render() { 
    const MapWithAMarker = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: ...,
        loadingElement: ...,
        containerElement: ...,
        mapElement: ...
      }),
      withScriptjs,
      withGoogleMap
    )(props =>
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={17}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: ..., lng: ... }}
      >
          {props.markers.map(marker => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.name}
              position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
              onClick={this.onToggleOpen}
            >
            {this.state.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen}> marker.key </InfoWindow>}
            </Marker>
          ))}


      </GoogleMap>
    );
    return (
        <section id="mapa">
            <div class= "container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                        <h2 class="section-heading">MAPA</h2>

                        <MapWithAMarker markers={this.state.markers}/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    ) 
}
```

EDIT: Updated code:

```
export default class Mapa extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      markers: [],
      isOpen: false
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
    let list = { restaurants : []}
    database.ref('..').on('value', restaurants => {
            restaurants.forEach( restaurant => {
                    list.restaurants.push({'name': restaurant.key,
                            'longitude': restaurant.val().lng,
                            'latitude': restaurant.val().lat}

                        )
            })
            this.setState({ markers:  list.restaurants });
        })

}

onToggleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
    }

render() { 

    const MapWithAMarker = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
      }),
      withScriptjs,
      withGoogleMap
    )(props =>
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={17}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: .., lng: ... }}
      >
          {props.markers.map(marker => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.name}
              position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
              onClick={this.onToggleOpen}
            >
            {this.state.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen}> marker.key </InfoWindow>}
            </Marker>
          ))}

      </GoogleMap>
    );
    return (
        <section id="mapa">
            <div class= "container">
            <h3 class="info-title"><span class="info-title-span">Tasty and Convenient.</span></h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-left">


                        <MapWithAMarker markers={this.state.markers}/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Just declare this in the render method and call it from there so it's in scope: `var isOpen = this.state.isOpen;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903246/react-google-maps-multiple-info-windows-opening-up Here you Go!

Answer (score 5):

The error indicates that `this.state == undefined` within the scope of where you are trying to retrieve `this.state.isOpen`.

This is because your `this.onToggleOpen()` function's scope is not properly bound to your component.

Try refactoring it to use an arrow function like so:

```
onToggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
}
```

---

Side note:

Best practice to declare initial `this.state` is to do so within your component's [`constructor`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) lifecycle method like so:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    markers: [],
    isOpen: false
  }
}
```

Also, should `this.state.isOpen` be a unique property for of each of your `markers` instead of a blanket value for all of them? So that you can open each marker individually, instead of all at once.

Example Solution:

```
// Dependencies.
import React from 'react'
// GoogleMap, etc ..

// Map.
export default class Map extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {markers: []}

  // Render.
  render() {

    // Map With A Marker.
    const MapWithAMarker = compose(
      withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>,
        containerElement: <div style={{height: `400px`}}/>,
        mapElement: <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>
      }),
      withScriptjs,
      withGoogleMap
    )(props =>
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={props.zoom} defaultCenter={{lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng}}>
        {props.markers.map(props => <RestaurantMarker key={props.name} {...props}/>)}
      </GoogleMap>
    )

    // Return Map.
    return (
      <section id="map">
        <div class= "container">
        <h3 class="info-title"><span class="info-title-span">Tasty and Convenient.</span></h3>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
              <MapWithAMarker 
                markers={this.state.markers}
                lat={37.7749}
                lng={122.4194}
                zoom={17}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row text-center">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )

  }

  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {

    // Download Restaurants.
    database.ref('..').on('value', restaurants => {

      // Restaurants Placeholder.
      let markers = []

      // Map Restaurants To List.
      restaurants.forEach(restaurant => {
        markers.push({
          'name': restaurant.key,
          'longitude': restaurant.val().lng,
          'latitude': restaurant.val().lat
        })
      })

      // Update State.
      this.setState({markers})

    })

  }

}


// RestaurantMarker.
class RestaurantMarker extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {open: false}

  // Render.
  render() {

    // Extract Props.
    const {name, latitude, longitude} = this.props

    // Return Restaurant Marker Component.
    return (
      <Marker key={name} position={{ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }}>
        {this.state.open && (
          <InfoWindow onClick={() => this.setState(state => ({open: !state.open}))}> {name} </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </Marker>
    )

  }

}
```

Comment: How could I make a property for each of the markers? Definitely I just want the info window for the marker I clicked.. Maybe passing the `isOpen` through props?

Comment: I would insert logic to check for an `isOpen` property for each of the `this.state.markers` children when rendering. ie. within your `props.markers.map()` function: `if (marker.isOpen) { // return open version of marker }`

Comment: I couldn't make it work... I tried to add `isOpen` in the `list.restaurants.push({..., isOpen: false})` and later `{marker.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen.bind(this)}> marker.key </InfoWindow>}`, but I don't know what to do on `onToggleOpen` function so I can change that props...

Comment: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#infowindow

In that example they made it through props? I can't find a way to make it work

Comment: You probs don't want to pollute your Firebase data with idiosyncratic UI state references such was what's open in your map. To keep things simple and segmented, try managing `isOpen` as it's own `Object {marker.id: bool}` in `this.state` and passing it as a prop in your `render()` function to your `MapWithAMarker` component. ie `<MapWithAMarker ... isOpen={this.state.isOpen}/>`.  That way you can manage what's open individually by a relevant unique id such as `marker.name` based on what `this.state.isOpen[marker.name]` returns.

Comment: The example you linked returns one single marker. Therefore, a blanket `isOpen` value is appropriate for their use case. 

There are a couple other solutions you could adopt such nesting all of the `<Marker>{content}</Marker>` logic that you return from `this.markers.map()` within it's own component class and returning that. You could then manage all of the idiosyncratic state independently from within each component you return. I would personally head in that sort of direction.

Comment: I just updated my code under the EDIT:. I tried to do what you suggested but I couldn't make it work. Could you post your suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Goood idea. I revised my answer to include an example of the sort of solution I'm talking about. Note the `<RestaurantMarker/>` component and logic therein to handle whether or not each marker is open in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm having this small issue: 

Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the top-level render call using `<GoogleMap>`. See react-warnings-keys for more information.
    in RestaurantMarker

Comment: My bad. React expects to see `keys` when handling `lists` of components. Simply add a key prop and pass a unique value to it, ie. restaurant.name. See [this tut](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info. I've revised the code above to include a unique `key` prop for each `<RestaurantMarker/>`.

Comment: as well you have to exclude the key prop in here:
`// Extract Props.
    const {
      props: {
        name,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        key
      }
    } = this`

The `onClick` event was on the `infoWindow`, I changed that to the `Marker`, and added `onCloseClick` to the `infoWindow`.

Thank you for all the help!! really appreciate it

Comment: I know this question is long answered, but the answer really helped me, particularly the example of `<RestaurantMarker>`, however the 'extract props' line is really confusing me - I can't quite understand what is happening. Is that just a lot of ES6 destructuring going on there? If so, can you possibly show an ES5 version? I love that it works, but I just can't quite grok why it does.  Is that just creating a constant of `{name}` from that marker instance's props.name?  What is the `= this` all about?  Is that so the marker retains its individual properties (like 'name') when 'clicked' later?

Comment: Correct. See above for simplified solution  @DaydreamNation

Comment: [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is common. My style, back then, was to just pull everything from [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in one go. I've since found that `nested destructuring assignment` isn't that nice to look at / confuses other devs. The revised approach is definitely superior @DaydreamNation

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the main wrapper

```
withStateHandlers(() => ({
    isOpen: {},
  }), {
    onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => (id) => ({
      isOpen: {
        ...isOpen,
        [id]:isOpen[id]==undefined?true:!isOpen[id]
      },
    })
  }),
```

And this on Marker component

```
{props.servicePoints.map((x) =>
        <Marker
          onClick={()=>{
            props.onToggleOpen(x.id);
          }}
          animation={google.maps.Animation.DROP}
          key={x.id}
          icon={"favicon.ico"}
          position={{ lat: x.latitude, lng: x.longitude }}
        >
          {props.isOpen[x.id]===true &&
            <InfoWindow
              key={x.id}
              options={{ closeBoxURL: ``, enableEventPropagation: true }}
              onCloseClick={()=>{
                props.onToggleOpen(x.id);
              }}>
              <div>
                <label>Nome:{x.name}</label><br></br>
                <label>Descrizione:{x.description}</label><br></br>
                <label>Indirizzo:{x.address}</label>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>}}
         </Marker>
      )}
```

All is working fine. So if I click one Marker, only one InfoWindow appear.